# My car want go into D but will go into 1st &2nd grear it's also been leaking transmission fluid what could be the problem 07 Buick lacrosse

Tags: transmission, gears, buick, lacrosse

2007 Buick GMC lacrosse CXL V6 Transmission fluid been leaking now it doesn't want to go into drive(D) but will go/work in 1st and 2nd

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you say "it won't go into drive", do you mean it doesn't engage (start the car moving)? Have you been replacing fluid as it leaks out (as in, keeping it topped off every evening or whenever)? How much has been leaking out? How long has the leak been going on?

Answer (score 0):

1. fluid can be contaminated or you are running very dry
2. Pressure-range sensor is busted
3. Check engine codes for the speed sensor circuit - can be another notable cause

This is just aside mechanical damage to the gears.